# Laravel eloquent not getting many-to-many related table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got OffersConntroller and I try to fetch all offers with specialities from other table (which is many-to-many relationship - working correctly)

Offer model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



class Offer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'body'
    ];

    public function specialities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Speciality');
    }
}
```

Speciality model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Speciality extends Model
{
    // protected $table = 'specialities';

    protected $casts = [
        'speciality_id'=>'string'
    ];

    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Offer');
    }
}
```

`specialities` table has `name, id,` 
`offer_speciality` table has `offer_id, speciality_id`

I'm trying to get name
so in OffersController:

```
public function index()
{
    return Offer::orderBy('created_at','desc')->with('specialities:name')->get();
}
```

And I got empty array "speciality" within correct the array of fetched offers

Comment: `'specialities:name'` will work fine if you're using Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order of the methods around:

```
Orders::with('specialities')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

Comment: this works, thank you, eloquent is very confusing on start